# Why is my <li> type not displayed?

Tags: html, css, list

This is my list

```
<ul class="list-inline row ">
<li  href="#" style="color:white"> Registrate  </li >
<li style="list-style-type:square; color:white" href="#">Quienes Somos  </li>
<li style="list-style-type:square; color:white"  href="#" style="color:white">Contacto   </li >
</ul>
```

This is my CSS

```
.list-inline { padding-left: 0;
margin-left: -5px;
list-style: none;
}
.list-inline > li {
display: inline-block;
padding-right: 5px;
padding-left: 5px;
}
```

I get the text and the color but I don't get the square!

Comment: Fix your html `li` elements don't have a `href` attribute.

Comment: Also the 'display: inline-block;' you gave to '.list-inline > li' seems to hide the square

Comment: remove the `list-style: none`

Comment: Your CSS needs to be rewritten a bit: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/62n4y/)

Comment: Donde all, and still, nothing!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`list-style-type:square` must go in your `ul` tag.

```
<ul class="list-inline row" style="list-style-type:square;">
```

Answer (score 4):

http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/list-style

Set the `list-style-type` on the `ul` element rather than the `li` elements.

```
<ul class="list-inline row " style="list-style-type: square;">
<li  style="color:white"> Registrate  </li >
<li style="color:white">Quienes Somos  </li>
<li style="color:white">Contacto   </li >
</ul>
```

Comment: as @IndieRok pointed out in the comments, you need to modify the css a little bit.  If you display the list inline it removes the decoration, so you need to float them left and add margin to have them properly spaced. http://jsfiddle.net/pEKD3/